# What is the algorithm of bcrypt?

Tags: encryption, passwords, bcrypt, algorithm

In many places I heard that people recommend to use the bcrypt algorithm to save passwords into database while creating web applications.I want to know what is the algorithm used to bcrypt a password in step by step.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking that is not clearly answered on [Wikipedia page for Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)? If you have a specific question please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Per [Wikipedia's article on bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), the algorithm is a modified version of the key setup process from the [Blowfish cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)), repeated thousands of times, using each round's output as the input for the next round.

Comment: @GrahamHill That describes the blowfish blockcipher, not the bcrypt password hash. While bcrypt is based on blowfish, they're not identical.